# PlotLegends question

Tags: legending

Two lists:

```
line = {{0, 2.15}, {0.05, 2.03}, {0.1, 1.94}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.3, 
1.68}, {0.4, 1.58}};
points = {{0.1009`, 1.206`}, {0.19455`, 1.4569`}, {0.3597`, 1.2315`}};
```

I'd like to plot the line with the points, and have a legend.

```
ListPlot[{line, points}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}, PlotLegends -> {"line", "points"}, PlotMarkers -> {" ", \[FilledSquare]}, Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Why doesn't PlotLegends pick up the line? Any way around this, other than manually?

Comment: Confused about what? I don't want markers on the first one. I want a line. I want the legend to exactly mirror what ListPlot is doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works automatically in Mathematica 10. Using your original input:

```
line = {{0, 2.15}, {0.05, 2.03}, {0.1, 1.94}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.3, 
    1.68}, {0.4, 1.58}};
points = {{0.1009`, 1.206`}, {0.19455`, 1.4569`}, {0.3597`, 1.2315`}};

ListPlot[{line, points}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"line", "points"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {" ", \[FilledSquare]}, Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Looking forward to trying it, especially to see legending and general scientific plotting. I'm especially curious whether tick marks can be customized more easily (perhaps with themes, or at least in interactive post-processing). That's just one of my eternal unresolved complaints.

Comment: You beat me to it. (+1)

Comment: So, yes. It wasn't functioning properly in 9. Thanks. Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

```
line = {{0, 2.15}, {0.05, 2.03}, {0.1, 1.94}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.3, 
    1.68}, {0.4, 1.58}};
points = {{0.1009`, 1.206`}, {0.19455`, 1.4569`}, {0.3597`, 1.2315`}};
```

With markers on line

```
ListPlot[{line, points},
 PlotRange -> {0, 2.5},
 PlotLegends -> {"line", "points"},
 PlotMarkers -> {{■, 12}, {●, 12}},
 Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Without markers on line

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[line,
  PlotLegends -> {"line"},
  PlotStyle -> Blue],
 ListPlot[points,
  PlotLegends -> {"points"},
  PlotMarkers -> {{●, 12}},
  PlotStyle -> Red],
 PlotRange -> {0, 2.5},
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Strange that the legend for the plot with a line *and* marker contains only the marker and not the line, isn't it? But you do get both in the second example using `ListLinePlot` if `PlotMarkers` is added there...

Comment: Klunky, but it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't pick up the line 'cause you telling not to do ...

```
PlotMarkers -> {" ", ■}
```

with the " " you just typeset an emty space. Try

```
ListPlot[{line, points}, PlotRange -> {0, 2.5}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"line", "points"}, 
 PlotMarkers -> {●, ■}, 
 Joined -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

check [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotMarkers.html).

Comment: I don't want the markers. Just the line. Even with your solution, there is no line in the legend. Just the marker..

Answer (score 0):

I get the same result as Brett Champion in version 11.3.0.0 given your code.  However, I encountered a similar problem when using LogPlot, which also uses the PlotLegends option in Version 11.3.0.0.

For the function:

```
labeledbifurcagtingrootedtrees[x_] := Module[{m}, m = x; (Factorial[((2*m)-3)])/((2^(m-2))*Factorial[m-2])]
```

and its plot:

```
p1 = LogPlot[labeledbifurcagtingrootedtrees[n], {n, 3, 14}, PlotStyle->Blue, PlotLegends->"Labeled Unrooted Trees"]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCd7O.png]

Note that the PlotLegend is missing.

However, simply by putting the string in a list, the problem goes away:

```
p1 = LogPlot[labeledbifurcagtingrootedtrees[n], {n, 3, 14}, PlotStyle->Blue, PlotLegends->{"Labeled Unrooted Trees"}]
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ4KS.png]

This is something not expected from the Documentation for PlotLegends.